# Returning a SwiftUI List in a function

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

When using SwiftUI, I like to create functions that return Views, it's just an easy way to separate and clean up the code. Like this:

```
func deleteButton() -> some View { return (Button...) }
```

This works like a charm, but when I try to return a List like this:

```
func itemsList() -> List<Never, some DynamicViewContent> { ... }
```

I get the error "'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions".
I tried it without "some", and just "DynamicViewContent" without List, but neither has worked.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option #1:

Return `some View`:

```
func myList() -> some View {
   List(items, id:\.self) { item in
     Text("Hello")
   }
}
```

Option #2:

Use the specific type. The easiest way I can think of to get this is to temporarily set a variable to the `List`. For example:

```
var myList = List(items, id:\.self) { item in
    Text("Hello")
}
```

If I then Option-Click on `myList`, Xcode will display a popup showing the exact type that `myList` is inferred to be. You can use that as the return type for your function. In the case of my contrived example, it is `List<Never, ForEach<[GameModel], GameModel, Text>>` where `items` is `[GameModel]`

Comment: Option 2 works perfectly (option 1 returns "some View" and I want to add .refreshable() and .searchable()), thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need to "cheat" to get the signature, the compiler can infer it: `let itemsList = { List(items, id:\.self) { item in
    Text("Hello")
} }`  ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper My suggestion is to let the compiler infer it. No cheating involved.

Comment: I guess, you confused me. As I understood it, you suggested to use the type signature and annotate the function `itemsList` with that signature.